# Data report in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6, report

I'm using data report in VB 6 and trying to display images from database. It retrieves the image but showing the same image for all output
the code i'm using are given below

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, rs1 As ADODB.Recordset

Dim a As String
k = 0
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0



Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rs

    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .Source = "SELECT patientid FROM Inpatients_Maintenance WHERE (ModDate >= '" & frmDate & "') AND (ModDate <= '" & endDate & "')"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open

    Do Until rs.EOF

    If (rs.EOF = False And rs.BOF = False) Then
    pid(i) = rs.Fields(0).Value

    End If
    i = i + 1
    rs.MoveNext

    Loop
End With

Set rs = Nothing
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim id As String
With rs1
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = conn

    For j = 0 To i - 1
        id = pid(j)
       .Source = "Select photo from patientImage where patientid='" & id & "'"
       .CursorLocation = adUseClient
       .Open


        If (rs1.EOF = False And rs1.BOF = False) Then
            p(j) = App.Path + "\patients\" + rs1.Fields(0).Value
            a = p(j)

            Set RptInpatientMaster.Sections("Section1").Controls("Image2").Picture = LoadPicture(a)

        End If
        .Close
    Next j
End With
```

Comment: sir
please help me out to solve this problem, i am in very much need.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you only see the last one?

```
Set RptInpatientMaster.Sections("Section1").Controls("Image2").Picture = LoadPicture(a)
```

you always refer to same picture inside your report, isn't it?